# C and Win32: Getting non-documented return value from GetFileAttributesW() function

Tags: c, windows, directory, bitmask, file-attributes

Language: C

Platform: Windows 10

Compiler: MinGW

I am obtaining a return value from the `GetFileAttributesW()` function (part of the Win32 API) equal to `17`, which does not match any of the file attribute macros listed [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/file-attribute-constants), nor is it equal to the macro INVALID_FILE_ATTRIBUTES (-1).

Upon calling GetLastError() after the function call, `ERROR_SUCCESS` is returned (0) - indicating no error. So I am perplexed as to what is going on.

The file in question (passed as a command-line argument) is my Downloads directory, which is why I find it odd that the value returned by GetFileAttributesW() (17) is only one number off of `FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY` (16).

Minimum reproducible example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#ifdef _WIN32
#include <windows.h>
#else
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#endif

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    if (argc != 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Invalid number of arguments provided.\n");
        return -1;
    }

#ifdef _WIN32
    int Argc;
    LPWSTR *dir = CommandLineToArgvW(GetCommandLineW(), &Argc);

    if (dir == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error getting command line arguments.\n");
        return -1;
    }
    DWORD fileAttribute = GetFileAttributesW(*(dir + 1));
    wprintf(L"fileAttribute: %d\n", fileAttribute);
#endif
    
    return 0;
}
```

There might be something simple that I'm missing, or perhaps there is no clear solution. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: It looks like `FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY | FILE_ATTRIBUTE_READONLY`.

Comment: @MikeCAT Oh crickey, I hadn't even realised that the return value could be a bitwise or combination of flags. Cheers, will go check that out right now. Would you then suggest doing a check for various different bitwise or'ed combinations?

Comment: Each bits corresponds to each flags. You can use bitwise AND with each flags to check if each flags are ON.

Comment: @MikeCAT that's brilliant, cheers. Hadn't even crossed my mind. Will work on that now.

Comment: @GregorWattersHärtl on a side note, you don't need `malloc()`, `wcscpy()` or `free()` in this example (you do need to `LocalFree()` the pointer returned by `CommandLineToArgvW()`, though). You can pass `dir[1]` as-is to `GetFileAttributesW()` instead (I would rename `dir` to `Argv`), eg: `int Argc; LPWSTR *Argv = CommandLineToArgvW(GetCommandLineW(), &Argc); ... DWORD fileAttribute = GetFileAttributesW(Argv[1]); ... LocalFree(Argv);`

Comment: @RemyLebeau cheers, thanks, it was only there because of how I use it in the rest of the program, but I'll remove it to make this example clearer! Thank you too though for the comment on LocalFree(), I hadn't heard about this function before

Comment: @GregorWattersHärtl "*I hadn't heard about [the LocalFree() function] before*" - then I take it that you did not read [`CommandLineToArgvW()`'s documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-commandlinetoargvw), did you? "*CommandLineToArgvW allocates a block of contiguous memory for pointers to the argument strings, and for the argument strings themselves; the calling application must free the memory used by the argument list when it is no longer needed. **To free the memory, use a single call to the LocalFree function**.*"

Comment: @RemyLebeau nope, I had not, so thanks for pointing this out to me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The return value is a bitmask, multiple flags can be combined using the bitwise OR operator.

The value `17` is `FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY | FILE_ATTRIBUTE_READONLY`.

You can use the `bitwise AND` operator to check if the value contains each flag.